# mod_deflate - possible to compress 1k or higher only? cache?

Tags: apache-http-server, compression, cache, htaccess

Is there a way to tell `mod_deflate` in `.htaccess` to only compress files if they are at least 1kb? Also, can it cache compression results? Once it compresses a file, I want it to use that again instead of attempting to compress it again.

Comment: Please put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, take a look at the `mod_deflate` docs here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html